# relation between smash product and suspension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

let $S$ be the d-sphere.
we know that $S \wedge X = \Sigma^d X$ the $d$-fold suspension of $X$.
what can we say about 
$(S\times S) \wedge (S\times S)$ in terms of suspension?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

That space it not a suspension. For instance, it has nontrivial products in its cohomology, unlike suspensions.
If you suspend your space once, it falls apart as a wedge of various spheres of dimensions d and 2d.